# Populating tabs dynamically with AngularJS with filtered data

Tags: json, angularjs, angular-filters

I have a json data

```
[
   {
      "name": "a",
      "data": "north",
      "value": "10",
      "finished": "50"
   },
   {
      "name": "b",
      "data": "south",
      "value": "100",
      "finished": "10"
   },
   {
      "name": "c",
      "data": "north",
      "value": "20",
      "finished": "50"
   },  
   {
      "name": "a",
      "data": "south",
      "value": "80",
      "finished": "10"
   } 
   ....
]
```

I want to dynamically add tabs if the "name" value is different and add the content in tab template. There could be multiple json array with the same name and that should go together in same tab.

I initially did:

```
for(var i=0;i<$scope.operation.length;i++) {   
   if($scope.operation[i].name === "a") {
      $scope.tab1 = {
           "title": "Data A" ,"path": "/data"
      };

    }
    if($scope.operation[i].name === "b"){
       $scope.tab2 = {
           "title": "Data B " ,"path": "/datab"
        };

     }
}
and so on ...
```

this method is not good if there are multiple different name values. Is there any optimization that i can do to filter.
And for templates I am displaying data using the filters which is again a bad method:

```
 // custom  filters  - should return data with name value "a" 
$scope.isDCone = function(data,id){
  return data.name === "a";
};

  // custom  filters  - should return data with name value "b"
   $scope.isDCtwo = function(data){
     return data.name === "b";
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **reduce** function

```
$scope.tabs = $scope.operation.reduce(function(a,b){
    if (a[b.name]){
        a[b.name].push(b);
    } else{
        a[b.name] = [b];
    }
    return a;
}, {});
```